# Не могу запустить jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

При зборке проекта и попытке деплоя вылетает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize
        at org.springframework.boot.convert.StringToDataSizeConverter.getConvertibleTypes(StringToDataSizeConverter.java:40)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$Converters.add(GenericConversionService.java:507)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConversionService.java:105)
        at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.addApplicationConverters(ApplicationConversionService.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.configure(ApplicationConversionService.java:91)
        at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.<init>(ApplicationConversionService.java:52)
        at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.<init>(ApplicationConversionService.java:45)
        at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.getSharedInstance(ApplicationConversionService.java:71)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.configureEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:486)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:346)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at com.statistic.server.Application.main(Application.java:9)
        ... 8 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Файл pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>5.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <springframework.boot.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</springframework.boot.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.2.Final</hibernate.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
    <commons-dbcp2.version>2.1.1</commons-dbcp2.version>
    <jackson-databind.version>2.9.6</jackson-databind.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON Converter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbcp2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Ошибка на мой взгляд не очень информативная, поэтому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значимая часть трассировки:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
```

Похоже, что у вас несовместимость версий между библиотеками Spring.

Comment: Догадывался, но как понять что версии совместимы?